# Not able to open the output file using a button assigned to it in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying populate word document using python and able to get the desired output file. However in the end, I am not able to open the output file using a button assigned to it. Kindly suggest

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from mailmerge import MailMerge
import os

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


def submit():
    template = "Template.docx"
    document = MailMerge(template)
    document.merge(Name='Rocky',
                   Age='25',
                  )
    document.write('test-output.docx')

def open_file():
    t = open('test-output.docx', 'r')


submit_btn = Button(root, text="SUBMIT", command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=19, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

open_btn = Button(root, text='OPEN OUTPUT FILE TO PRINT', command=open_file)
open_btn.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you expect `t = open('test-output.docx', 'r')` to do?  This code will open the file for reading in Python and then not do anything with it.  You leave the file open with no way to access its handle since `t` goes out of scope without ever being saved anywhere else.

Comment: I got it, os.system('start test-output.docx') did the job.